# Compiling multiple Typescript files into one javascript file

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am using tsc.exe manually, is there a way for me to basically pass it a load of Typescript files under a root namespace and just compile it to a single namespace encapsulated js file?

I am thinking like how you have a .net dll which contains the root namespace and all children.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to find some links after posting this:

[TypeScript compiling as a single JS file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12926830/typescript-compiling-as-a-single-js-file)
http://www.codebelt.com/typescript/typescript-compiler-commands/

Both of which helpped me, the actual answer is:

```
tsc.exe --out some_file.js some_ts_file.ts some_other_ts_file.ts
```