# TypeScript bundling and minification?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, typescript, asp.net-mvc-5

Assume I have two files

AFile.ts

```
/// <reference path="ZFile.ts" />
new Z().Foo();
```

ZFile.ts

```
class Z
{
    Foo() { }
}
```

Is there a way to generate all scripts in a single `js` file in the order it requires (need `ZFile` before `AFile` to get the definition of `Z`)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Now VS Typescript Extension supports merging to one file.
Make sure that you have installed the extension `Tools -> Extensions and Updates` (VS2015 has it by default)

[image]

Go to the project properties and check `Combine JavaScript output into file`:
[image]

Important to have `/// <reference />` (as in question), it helps `tsc`  order files by dependencies before the merge.

---

Then for minimisation bundle can be used as usual:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/finale").Include("~/js/all.js"));
```

and in view

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/finale")
```

Comment: Will this also work with other module types like System? Is it possible to use this instead of module loaders like webpack or babel, ie. node packages?

Comment: This UI is disabled on my machine. Any idea why?

Comment: Also, this builds JS files form TS files during Build. Isn't there a way to do this on the fly with a bundle configuration? :^)

Answer (score 14):

In post build events I added a call to `TypeScript` compiler

```
tsc "..\Content\Scripts\Start.ts" --out "..\Content\Scripts\all.js"
```

In the bundle configuration I added

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/scripts/all").Include("~/Content/Scripts/all.js"));
```

On the `_Layout.cshtml` file I added

```
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/all")
```

And with that I got

```
<script src="/Scripts/all?v=vsTcwLvB3b7F7Kv9GO8..."></script>
```

Which is all my script in a single file.

---

The compiler does not minify, you have to use bundles and compile on Release or set

```
BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
```

You can also minify using Web Essentials or grabbing the contents and minifing somewhere else.

Comment: How do you stop it from automaticly compiling on save? Do yo have to specify each file or can we use wildcards?

Comment: You can use `IncludeDirectory()` to include all the files :-)
See also : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12926830/typescript-compiling-as-a-single-js-file

Comment: Is it wrong in the bundle to have .Include("~/Content/Scripts/all.ts")); ?

Answer (score 4):

Use the --out parameter.

```
tsc AFile.ts ZFile.ts --out single.js
```

The typescript compiler will do the dependency navigation for you automatically.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming all of your ts files are directly or indirectly under a folder called say 'ts' you could write a tt script which merged all of .js files(but not min.js) into a file myApp.js and all of your min.js files into myApp.min.js.

To obtain the ordering of files you could process subfolders thus:

```
string[] FolderOrder =
{
    @"libs\utils\",
    @"libs\controls\",
    @"app\models",
    @"app\viewmodels",
    @".",
};
```

Comment: What's a tt script?