# TypeScript + Visual Studio 2013 - How to use TypeScript from other assembly?

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2013, typescript

Say I have TypeScript code in assembly A. Now I want to write unit tests in TypeScript (using Jasmine) in assembly B (to separate the tests from implementation), how can I reference TypeScript in assembly A from assembly B in Visual Studio 2013? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use following approach:

- In project A we generate a single resulting .js file, let's say "code.js".
- In the directory of the project B we create a symlink to the "code.js" file.
- In project B we have "tests.html" page (we use qunit), where "code.js" is being included as script reference. Project B contains unit tests only.

Update:

"TypeScript compiling as a single JS file" is described in this [stackoverlow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12926830/typescript-compiling-as-a-single-js-file). You can also find a lot of information about this.

Symlinks were been created via "prepare.cmd" file (in the solution folder) with lines like

mklink "ProjectB\libraries\your_code.js" "..\..\ProjectA\CompileResults\your_code.js"

As for unit tests - i'm shure you know about Jasmine more than I ;)

Comment: Thanks TSV! Could you provide more details on how you accomplished the steps? Any tutorials or guides I can use?