# Visual Studio can not combine JavaScript output into one file. Is there any adjustment am I needed to do more?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-2013, typescript, commonjs

[image]

Settings I set before built are as seen picture above. I don't know what should i do extra to accomplish to combine all .ts files into one single .js file.

Answer (score 4):

If using VS2015 RTM version it turns out they broke it.

You need to put full pathname here until they fix it.

[image]

[VS2015 Typescript compile to single file on save not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31559653/vs2015-typescript-compile-to-single-file-on-save-not-working)

**Upvote this** : https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1581065/typescript-compile-output-into-single-file-not-working-on-save

Answer (score 2):

Set module system to `none` and make sure you are not using `external modules`. These do not work with `--out` at the moment.

Difference : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KDrWLMUY0R0&hd=1

If you want a single file from commonjs modules you need to use something like webpack or browserify. TS won't do it : https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17

Comment: But i am using external commonjs modules. Eventhough, i need to combine them. Do you have any idea how to do this ?