# VS2015 Typescript compile to single file on save not working

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2015

I have trouble with VS 2015 and Typescript compile on save. If I enable combine all outputs into one file that output file will not be updated on save. During build the file gets updated correctly.
Some times there is an error message in the status bar which states the .map file can't be written.
If i disable the one file option compile on save is working.
Is there any option to enable some logging so I could figure out what is going wrong?

**Update:**
I was able to reproduce this with a new clean Project and also on another PC of a collegue with a completeely different existing project. So this seems to be a general bug.

Comment: for anyone new to VS2015 that was not using CTPs I can confirm that this was a bug introduced in the RTM version - relative paths have worked just fine until now

Comment: this is a trivial thing for MS to fix - but please everyone upvote it here so it can get some boosted priority https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1581065  (this was opened by Denis)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, I reproduced this too

You need to set full path for JavaScript file

Comment: Nice workaround and Thanks, but Is there any other way to do so with relative path?

Comment: I tried with `$(SolutionDir)\combined.js` and even with an environmental variable `%PUBLIC%` and it didn't work

Comment: note: $(SolutionDir) or $(ProjectDir) syntax doesn't work (it was just an attempt to get it working). The path is relative to the project directory so with v 1.5.4 or above just type `Scripts/combined.js` or whatever path you want

Answer (score 6):

This has been fixed.

Go to `Extensions and Updates`. Update to version `1.5.4` or above and it should work.

The upgrade process is a little odd because a new Visual Studio installer will appear on top of the current instance. Close the Visual Studio underneath and then continue with the update to avoid conflicts.

It took quite a surprising length of time (over a minute) to apply the update but it works fine now.

Note: When making a `.ts` file to then save change you must make a real code change, not just type something, delete it and save or it won't be recognized.

[image]

Comment: I'm running 1.5.4 and still have the same problem. Using the absolute path works but not when using ${ProjectDir}

Comment: You don't use $, just something like Scripts/typescript/combined.js

Answer (score 2):

Full path is fine until you have to start building on different machines.

I for instance use `R:\TFS-PROJECTS` on my local machine but `C:\TFS-PROJECTS` on the TFS server (which also builds the typescript).

As a temporary solution I'm using `junction.exe` to make symbolic link (run as admin).

```
junction c:\TFS-PROJECTS r:\TFS-PROJECTS
```

That way I can just use the same full path. If you have vastly different hierarchies you could use `C:\PROJECT1-ROOT` and point that wherever you need.

[image]

Junction is a sysinternals program available for Microsoft  :https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896768

Hoping a fix for this regression bug will be deployed soon.

Comment: This has since been fixed. See my other answer (I'm not quite sure how I ended up with two answers :-/)

Answer (score 1):

It's an old question, but I had a different resolution:

Make sure your TypeScript version is installed/available. I'd opened an old project and it was set as `3.6 (unavailable)`. Updating the version to 3.8 (which was installed) fixed it.

[image]