# TypeScript "Compile on save" feature not working in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, compilation, typescript, visual-studio-2015

The "Compile on save" feature isn't working for me after upgrading to Visual Studio 2015.  When I make a change to a `.ts` file in my project and save, the status bar at the bottom of the IDE says `Output(s) generated successfully`, but the generated `.js` file doesn't change.

Here's what I've tried:

- adding the following to the root `<Project>` element in my `.csproj`:

  ```
  <PropertyGroup>
      <TypeScriptCompileOnSaveEnabled>True</TypeScriptCompileOnSaveEnabled>
  </PropertyGroup>
  ```
- checking and unchecking the "Automatically compile TypeScript files which are not part of a project" option in `Tools -> Options -> TypeScript -> Project`:

  [image]
- double checking to make sure "Compile on save" is checked in my project's TypeScript Build properties:

  [image]

What am I missing?

As a side note, the TypeScript compilation step does work as expected when triggered by a regular build.

Comment: Check to make sure the JS files are NOT actually getting updated.  I ran into an issue with VS2013 for awhile where the 'JS Preview' was not updating, but the JS files were actually updating.  Manually open one to see if the code updated.  The cause of this was unknown but the solution was to shut down VS and reopen it.  I have not tried building any TS files in VS2015 yet.

Comment: They broke it for RTM. See this question

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31559653/vs2015-typescript-compile-to-single-file-on-save-not-working/31765536#31765536

Comment: I works when you run visual studio as administrator!

Comment: @alisabzevari Thanks for the suggestion, but running as administrator doesn't fix this issue for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This issue seems to have been resolved with the most recent update to the `TypeScript Language Services` extension.

[See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32031931/1063392) for instructions on how to apply this update.

Answer (score 145):

For me it was this option in `tsconfig.json`:

```
"compileOnSave": true,
"compilerOptions": { ... },
```

Restart Visual Studio for this change to take effect.

Comment: Using angular2, updated my typescript amongst many other things for rc1 and naturally everything broke until I eventually found that this was my issue. Hadn't needed it until I updated to 1.8.10.

Comment: yes, add the option in tsconfig.json and reload the project if the project is hosted in a VS solution. Then ts will be compiled to js on save.

Comment: Adding `"watch": true` to `compilerOptions` worked for me on Visual Studio 2015 Update 2 with Typescript 1.8.29.0

Comment: At some point around the time of TypeScript 2, Visual Studio shifted from keeping these settings in the `.csproj` file to just using the `tsconfig.json`. If your project's properties TypeScript page is not disabled, it likely means you have an old version of the TypeScript tools for Visual Studio installed and you should install https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48593

Answer (score 33):

I stumbled upon this problem today: I fixed that by using the new `"watch":true` compiler option, also available through JSON in most recent TypeScript versions:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "watch": true
  }
}
```

After doing that, I had to solve another issue related to the following error that appeared in the output window:

```
Object doesn't support property or method 'watchFile'
```

It turned out that my system was using an outdated version of **TypeScript** (1.0.x), despite I was sure I had a newer one that came with the **Visual Studio 2015 Update 1** (1.7). If you run into this problem, you can easily check your tsc version by typing `tsc -v` from a command-prompt.

If it says `1.0.x` or anything < 1.7, it's probably due to the fact that you have some old references in your PATH environment variable. Be sure you have 1.7 or later installed by checking inside your Microsoft SDKs folder, which is the one used by Visual Studio to install the TypeScript packages as they get updated:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript
```

If not, update accordingly. Open **CPanel** > **System** > **Advanced** > **Environment Variables**, select **System Variables** and click on **Edit**; browse through the list looking for any reference to the TypeScript folder, change one of them to make it point to your TypeScript most recent installed version (`1.7` or above) and delete any other dupes. See also screenshot below:

[image]

For additional details, read [this post](http://www.ryadel.com/en/fixing-typescript-compile-on-save-feature-in-visual-studio-2015-asp-net-5-rc1/) on my blog.

Comment: For me on win10, the name in the list was "Path" and not system variables. When you select that (its value is a long semicolon-concatenated string), and then click edit you get the modal window shown in this answer. My solution was NOT to add compileroptions > watch > true, but to set compileOnSave > true (one step up from compileroptions)

Comment: For me, setting this option caused a build error JsErrorScriptException (0x30001). After searching, I came accross this issue https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7362 . Miłosz Wierzbicki's solution (setting "compileOnSave") works for me, but only after restarting VS.

Comment: I had the same problem. U and @zedd saved me lots of hours.
This post is also helpful: http://www.ryadel.com/en/fixing-typescript-compile-on-save-feature-in-visual-studio-2015-asp-net-5-rc1/.

Answer (score 11):

Solution:

For me, and I am quite sure this is also the case for others, this was due to a mistake in the tsconfig.json.

You need to add "compileOnSave": true. But in the global section not inside compilerOptions.

```
Wrong:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "compileOnSave": true

  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "wwwroot"
  ]
}

Correct:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5"

  },
"compileOnSave": true,
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "wwwroot"
  ]
}
```

Best regards,

Anders Both
Basechat.

Answer (score 3):

With typescript 2 you have to delete "outDir": from your tsconfig. Fixed the bug for me in visual studio.

Comment: Where is the outdir tsconfig? Thx

Comment: @jay 
You do not see the option in the configuration file tsconfig.json of typescript?

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I had installed Visual Studio Community 2015 along side VS 2012.  I had been using Web Essentials for typescript in 2012 which appeared to conflict with 2015.

Uninstalling Web Essentials in 2012 fixed the issue for me.

Comment: I'm using VS Community and uninstalling Web Essentials did the trick for me.  Thanks and upvoted!

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this will help anyone.

I though I was having issues compiling, but it was compiling on save. I just didn't have my solution explorer toolbar toggled to show all files.

The file was there, just waiting impatiently  to be added to the project.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In project properties -> "TypeScript Build", you can also simply just uncheck "Do not emit outputs if any errors are reported." Having it checked seems to deactivate transpiling on save, where there is an error or not.

Answer (score 1):

The `"compileOnSave": true,` wasn't working for me.  I finally figured out that Visual Studio doesn't honor the `"compileOnSave": true,` value if it is defined in another `.json` file that you're extending.  It has to be in the root in order for it to work.

Answer (score 1):

locate the file i.e. C:\file.ts in your `terminal/cmd` and type

```
tsc file.ts -w // watches for file changes and converts on save
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have the TypeScript version installed which is configured in the project. Somehow I received no warning that I don't have TypeScript 3.7 installed, but the compile-on-save feature stopped working silently.

Once I installed TypeScript 3.7, it was working again.

Answer (score 0):

Exact same problem here. 
I am using Visual Studio 2015 update 3 and TypeScript 2.9.2.0. In tools/options/projects and solutions/external web tools, I upgraded $(PATH) to the second position. 
With all these configurations, compileOnSave: true doesn't work for me. The workaround solution is open a command line, run `ng build --watch` on the side and let node take care of auto compilation

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar but not the same issue in Visual Studio 2019

- My project was set up to use TypeScript 2.9
- I had TypeScript 3.8 installed, and the code did compile, but wouldn't compile on save

I installed the older version, TypeScript 2.9, restarted VS and then it burst into life