# Cannot compile .ts file on save with typescript.config file included in project - VS 2015 update 3

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-2015, typescript1.8

I am using VS 2015 with update 3 and Typescript 1.8.10 installed globally with npm. But I cannot compile .ts file on save. It compiles fine if I run tsc command from command prompt and on building the project. It even works if I delete typescript.config file from the project. But with the config file in the project, it does not compile the .ts file on save.

I looked [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6782) thread on github but in vain. Has anyone come across this issue? And how can I resolve this?

Much appreciated.

Comment: "Does not compile.." - does nothing happen?  Do you get an error?

Comment: No Errors.. its just does not compile.

Comment: Does it compile the file when you build the solution?

Comment: @SteveGreatrex Yes it does compile on building the solution.

Comment: Have you enabled Compile on Save (as [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31750964/typescript-compile-on-save-feature-not-working-in-visual-studio-2015))?

Comment: @SteveGreatrex yes I did all of that.. it works if I remove the typescript.config file.. but not with the file included in the project.