# refresh javascript from typescript visual studio

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, typescript, visual-studio-2015

I have read this post below:

[Type Script is not generating JavaScript in my Visual Studio Community edition 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31845721/type-script-is-not-generating-javascript-in-my-visual-studio-community-edition-2)

[VS2015 Typescript compile to single file on save not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31559653/vs2015-typescript-compile-to-single-file-on-save-not-working/32031931#32031931)

[TypeScript "Compile on save" feature not working in Visual Studio 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31750964/typescript-compile-on-save-feature-not-working-in-visual-studio-2015)

Regarding:
"Do you bundle the JavaScript / TypeScript with another Tool?"

I am not sure whether I bundle the javascript with another tool or not. I am just using the default typescript functionality from visual studio 2015.

my probem is different. everytime I modify and save the typescript file, I have to stop debugging and start debugging again in visual studio so the javascript sync with the new typescript. is it possible not to do this? can i just save the typescript file without havign to redebug for the visual studio to refresh the javascript file? i am using visual studio 2015

this is my tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [ "es2015", "dom" ],
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "compileOnSave": true,
    "watch": true
  }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you include the tsconfig.json from your project? How are the JavaScripts are integrated into the page? Do you bundle the JavaScript / TypeScript with another Tool?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeScript "Compile on save" feature not working in Visual Studio 2015](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31750964/typescript-compile-on-save-feature-not-working-in-visual-studio-2015)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the answer.

as described in https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2375

just run the following on command prompt on your web project folder and ensure you have tsconfig.json:

```
tsc --watch
```

and not sure why, as opposed to most advice, do NOT include :

```
 "compileOnSave": true,
    "watch": true
```

in the tsconfig.json. otherwise `tsc --watch` won't work.

If you execute the command prompt properly, everytime you change your ts file, you should see the following log in your command prompt:

[image]