# Swagger-Codegen: How do I consolidate all files into one file for Client-Code-Generation

Tags: javascript, angular, express, swagger, swagger-codegen

I’ve just got started with Swagger and NodeJS. I was able to implement Swagger to my NodeExpress application and was also able to generate typescript-client-code with Swagger-Codegen (Typescript-Angular) to be exact.

One problem that I have is the generated code is so spread out many different files. I was hoping that it only output one file `api.ts` and it contains everything from API calls and interfaces/models.

I’ve been looking for a way to solve this problem because it is hard to read and maintain the generated-client-code as the backend grows.

Any suggestions or pointers would be much appreciated.

Happy Holiday! Thank you

EDIT: I have been looking for answers for this for a couple of days and still haven't found one. I'm currently working on a project with ASP.NET Core and they have `NSwag` which does what I want to achieve with `Node Swagger`.

Comment: i currently have a single file generated instead of multiple files - and i would want the opposite, do you mind sharing your config for getting it done such that the o/p is multiple files instead of one? I tried using it against the petStore.json and it generated a single file

Comment: @Jaya before I answer, may I ask if we're on the same page here? (typescript-angular, swagger-codegen 2.3.0)?

Comment: I use `swagger-js-codegen: ^1.12.0` defined here https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen#where-is-javascript and typescript for vuejs.. basically trying to generate ts models & ts client for an api that exposes its swagger.json file.

Comment: Use Swagger-codegen to generate typescript-fetch client stub and you should be good to go ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### TL; DR

You may compile all files into a single `*.ts` file as shown at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12926830/typescript-compiling-as-a-single-js-file).

#### Continuous Integration Approach

Swagger code generator simplifies maintenance because it allows you to think in terms of *continuous integrations*.

You should not be worried about code review or aesthetics (because it is a machine generated code), but about:

- API versioning
- Functions, methods and classes signatures
- Documentation

If you are working with a CI system such as Jenkins or Ansible, you could automatically deploy the library to a [private NPM account](https://docs.npmjs.com/private-modules/intro) (for JS and TS) or [Maven server](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-setup-private-maven-repository/en) (for Java and Kotlin).

[image: Private Maven]

Keeping the package version number consistently updated will allow the IDE to correctly prompt the user about updates on the API.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Though I am over this consolidation thing but this answer provides an accurate solution.

Comment: For NPM packages, you also can use GitHub repositories if you properly provide versioning tags as shown at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16350673

Answer (score 4):

Swagger uses Mustache templates for generating the code. For making simpler
changes you can simple create a copy of one of the [built-in templates](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/tree/master/modules/swagger-codegen/src/main/resources) and
modify that.

Then you can use your modified template like this:

```
swagger-codegen-cli generate -t path/to/template/dir/ -i spec.json
```

The output directory structure, however, cannot be changed using templates
alone. For that you'd need a custom codegen module. You can either [create your
own](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen#making-your-own-codegen-modules) or modify one of the [built-in ones](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/tree/master/modules/swagger-codegen/src/main/java/io/swagger/codegen/languages).