# Importing classes works at design time but not at runtime

Tags: node.js, typescript

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 (Update 3), Node.js Tools v1.0.20721.02 and Node.js v0.10.31

I'm trying to put each class into its own file.
At design time everything seems fine, intellisense is working and the code compiles without issues.
At runtime however, node tells me it cannot find the classes.

I've reproduced this again and again by creating a new Node console project in Visual Studio

**SomeClass.ts**

```
export class SomeClass
{
    name: string;

    constructor(name: string)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

**app.ts**

```
///<reference path="Scripts/typings/node/node.d.ts"/>

import some = require("SomeClass");

var instance = new some.SomeClass("Batman");
console.log(instance.name);
```

The generated javascript output looks like this:

**SomeClass.js**

```
var SomeClass = (function () {
    function SomeClass(name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    return SomeClass;
})();
exports.SomeClass = SomeClass;
//# sourceMappingURL=SomeClass.js.map
```

**app.js**

```
///<reference path="Scripts/typings/node/node.d.ts"/>
var some = require("SomeClass");

var instance = new some.SomeClass("Batman");
console.log(instance.name);
//# sourceMappingURL=app.js.map
```

**Runtime output**

> module.js:340
>      throw err;
>
> Error: Cannot find module 'SomeClass'
>      at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
>   ...

**Visual Studio Solution structure**

[image]

This is a standard solution created by the project template in Visual Studio,
shouldn't it just work out of the box?

I've seen quite a few related questions, including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12913238/cannot-load-class-from-file-in-typescript), which seem to solve the
the issues most people are having, but don't seem to solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `require("./SomeClass")` instead:

node.js resolves `require` differently when there is no path prepended ([see here](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_node_modules_folders)), so in this case you need to tell it to look in the current directory, not for a core module or inside an (inexistent) `node_modules` directory.

Further info on why it does not fail before runtime, given by the OP in the comments:

> Apparently VS resolves everything whether you prepend './' or not and at runtime node requires './' to be prepended.

Answer (score 0):

Run your program again adding the following line before your require:

```
console.log("cwd:%s", process.cwd());
```

And adjust the path you require so it starts at your current working directory (cwd).

Comment: As in specify the full path in the require("f:\..\..\...") That doesn't seem to work nor does it make much sense. It should not be machine dependent.

Comment: Not the best solution, but it hints at the likely problem. Try using `require("./SomeClass")`. node.js resolves `require` differently when there is no path prepended ([see here](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_node_modules_folders))

Comment: TimothyP, rather than being machine-dependent, Node resolves requires by attempting to find its target in the `node_modules` directory in the current working directory, then in `node_modules` in its parent directory, continuing up to the root directory. If you want to require modules outside of this strategy, you need to specify their paths either absolutely or relatively to the cwd.

Comment: I've added a screenshot of the solution explorer, because this stuff should just work out of the box.

Comment: @yerforkferchips You are correct, that solved the problem. Apparently VS resolves everything whether you prepend './' or not and at runtime node requires './' to be prepended. That solved the issue. If you put it as an answer I can even mark it as the solution